# Take element ( ID ) and show it anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a tricky question and i have very little knowledge of JS, Well, I am trying to pick an element from page and show it on anywhere by calling it.

Actually, that element coming from different source in header, and i want to show it in content area. Used Margin-top with -1000px value but on different page it render on different height of page. sometimes in heading an sometimes overlapping text because i can"t make it exact on every page.

So, I looking for a solution to pick that element and call it in specific area of webpage and i hide it with some css

```
 <div id="places"> <img src="foo.png"/></div>
```

So, Is there any way to pick places from webpage and call it anywhere in webpage again.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a var that stores the value and then add that value to the other div.

The div with your content:

```
<div id="places"> <img src="foo.png"/></div>
```

The div where you want to display the content from other div:

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var places = $('#places').html(); //grab html from first div
    $('#my_div').append(places); //add html to second div
});
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d64q6z9p/1/)

Comment: Actually you need to use `.html()` instead of `.val()`, just updated with demo.

Comment: Should work ok, 1.8.3... http://jsfiddle.net/d64q6z9p/2/, I edited my answer from original as noted in above comment check out the fiddle and make sure your code matches.

Comment: One thing, If i use display:none for places div then it wont break your js code?

Comment: Worked with display:none, Thank you so much for solving my problem.